# Reproducible android builds with git with fast forward merges

Tags: android, git, git-merge, repository, fast-forward

I'm looking reproducibility between android system (AOSP) daily builds against repo's collections of git repositories and the impact of using fast-forward merges.

The problem is that when doing daily builds you will get a tip-of-tree while development is happening elsewhere.  If HEAD hasn't changed when the change is pushed, it will do a fast-forward merge and time will be re-written.  So effectively the physical state of the repository 3 days ago will be different than asking git to go back three days.

The prime solution I can see is to use git with --no-ff to force merge commits. This injects a lot of noise for smaller commits, and seems to be considered bad practice in keeping a clean tree.

The background on this is trying to have reproducibility in an android build environment.  For those that don't know, an android build is a collection of disparate git repositories.  My ultimate use case is that I want to be able to say, put the code base in the state it was for developers 3 days ago.  With fast-forward merges, we lose some critical information on how to correlate between changes on multiple repo projects (ie: git repositories).

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, Git doesn't track the state of a branch over time. Two reasonable options are to either set tags for each build or to create a static manifest with the SHA-1s of all checked out commits at the time of the build:

```
repo manifest -r -o build_20131104.xml
```

Those files can either be checked into the manifest git and used like e.g.

```
repo init -u ... -m build_20131104.xml
```

to reproduce the prior state or you can save the files elsewhere.

Tagging all the gits litters the tag namespace if you're doing a lot of builds (and Git is currently fairly slow with thousands of tags) but is otherwise pretty convenient. Don't forget to tag the manifest git too.